# Devise routing error for signout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am deploying devise in my application and I am getting the following error when I try to sign out:-

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

I have checked *rake routes* and I can see that there isn't a route for GET but there is a route for DELETE. I understand from researching the issue that the GET is turned into a DELETE by *JQuery*. I have *JQuery* installed and it is in my GEMFILE:-

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I also have JQuery required in my application.js file:-

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I have made sure that the sign out link is correct and in fact I have tried two forms:-

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

And following some other advice I added this to my application.html file:-

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

I don't want to include the line below in the devise.rb file as this is just masking the real cause:-

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

However I have got it working by using this instead of the sign out link:-

```
<%= button_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)%>
```

The funny thing is that this was working yesterday and for some reason now isn't. At the same time the notices/alerts for devise in application.rb were working yesterday and they now aren't working either.

EDIT - I have now created a simple script in a page and the only way I can get this working is to add the following to the page itself (doesn't work if I add this to application.html):-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Without this the following script wont work:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
});
</script>
<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
```

And I get this error in the console:-

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I assumed that if *JQuery* was loading correctly this script should just work??

EDIT - A bit more information; if I add my test *jQuery* code to a devise view it works. *jQuery* is not being loaded by pages in my subfolders outside of devise - I can see in the source of the page that there are no script references in pages outside of the devise views.

In fact there is no html head section appearing at all, it clearly is not including anything from application.html.

**SOLVED** - but I cant answer my own question now for some reason. See comments below.

Comment: I think this might be related to the fact that I am using custom controllers?

Comment: I have added a JavaScript alert to application.js and I was expecting it to just show me the message when i loaded the root page but it doesn't. Does this mean JQuery isn't working?

Comment: I have solved this issue now but for some reason I cannot answer my own question any longer. Anyway, the issues was with my controllers, they were inheriting from an incorrect class.